# A dry way to build page with multiple blocks (from different controllers) and ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, render, dry

Main page of my website consists of multiple blocks such as last offers, last news, last articles and so on. Each block has controls like "show more" or "refresh" so that when user clicks, the block should refresh or update it's own content through ajax.
Also when a page is loaded the first time, it should already be filled with content (for disabled javascript and search engines).

What's the best, dry, rails-way to build such structure?

That's In my articles_controller.rb:

```
def line
  @articles = Article.filter(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => false, :partial => "articles/line.html", :locals => {:articles => @articles} }
    format.json { render :json => { "html" => render_to_string(:partial => "articles/line.html", :locals => {:articles => @articles}) } }
  end
end
```

When I call /articles/line through ajax it sends json that contains cut of html-code, and all that remains is to append it to a specified div. This works. When I call /articles/line directly it also works and displays required partial of html-code.

But what should I write in my main_controller (it should collect and render all blocks from different controllers)? Where should I write some blocks settings (for example, quantity of records and offset, they required both in static and ajax cases)?

Most convenient for me is to set everything up right in the view template of main page, like that:

```
<div id="last-news" data-params="{offset:0,limit:5}">
  <%= render #here we get html from :controller => news, :action => list, :params => get them from parent div %>
</div>
<div id="last-articles" data-params="{offset:0,limit:10}">
  <%= render #here we get html from :controller => articles, :action => list, :params => get them from parent div %>
</div>
```

But that doesn't look like MVC.

Comment: just a hint: if you use `render @article` in your view, rails will look after a `articles/_article.html.erb` partial (based on the model name of your `@article`) for rendering, whatever controller makes the call. You still have to set `@article` in your main controller, though. For your other problem, you can inspire yourself from / use [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)

Comment: Have you tried apotomo: http://apotomo.de? It's awesome.

Comment: Ok, so far I just created a new action called ajax in ApplicationController, so that this action is included to any other and there I generate both html and ajax versions of articles, news and offers lists. That's messy but at least dry. And thanks for apotomo.de